# Perl script getting stuck in terminal for no apparent reason

Tags: perl, cygwin, freeze, blocked

I have a Perl script which reads three files and writes new files after reading each one of them. Everything is one thread.

In this script, I open and work with three text files and store the contents in a hash. The files are large (close to 3 MB).

I am using a loop to go through each of the files (open -> read -> Do some action (hash table) -> close)

I am noticing that the whenever I am scanning through the first file, the Perl terminal window in my Cygwin shell gets stuck. The moment I hit the enter key I can see the script process the rest of the files without any issues.

It's very odd as there is no read from STDIN in my script. Moreover, the same logic applies to all the three files as everything is in the same loop.

Has anyone here faced a similar issue? Does this usually happen when dealing with large files or big hashes?

I can't post the script here, but there is not much in it to post anyway.
Could this just be a problem in my Cygwin shell?

If this problem does not go away, how can I circumvent it? Like providing the enter input when the script is in progress? More importantly, how can I debug such a problem?

```
sub read_set
{
@lines_in_set = ();
push @lines_in_set , $_[0];
while (<INPUT_FILE>) 
    {   $line = $_;
          chomp($line);
          if ($line=~ /ENDNEWTYPE/i or $line =~ /ENDSYNTYPE/ or eof())
          {
          push @lines_in_set , $line;
          last;
          }
          else 
          {
          push @lines_in_set , $line;       
          }
    }
    return @lines_in_set;
}
```

--------> I think i found the problem :- or eof() call was ensuring that the script would be stuck !! Somehow happening only at the first time. I have no idea why though

Comment: 3MB does not a huge file make.  I suggest you post some code so that we can help you with it.  Take your existing code, boil it down to the shortest snippet that will still exhibit the behavior, and then edit your question here to include that code.

Comment: 3MB is not a huge file. We can't debug without seeing code; voting to close.

Comment: @Wooble: Give him a minute to update it.  Closing questions that just require more information just prompts the user to redundantly post the question a few minutes later with more info.

Comment: unfortunately i can't share the code..i'm sorry about the incovenience... Please close this question if necessary..Thanks a lot for the help and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @user1566968 :Don't share the code.  Share a snippet of code that exhibits the exact same behavior.  Also, the simple act of boiling it down to a small test snippet often uncovers what you're doing wrong; you're likely to discover it yourself.  Rest assured that there *is* a solution.  What you're experiencing is not expected behavior when doing simple file reads.

Comment: Are you reading using `<>` with the file names in `@ARGV`?

Comment: i've added the code...after using the debugger i realized that i'm stuck at the line :- push @lines_in_set , $line;

Comment: @user1566968 - use the "BASIC" debugging technique (dibs on the term) - put "print" statements before and after every line in your program. Then it will show you which exact place it is stuck without need for a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eof()` call is the problem.  See [`perldoc -f eof`](http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/docs/perldoc-html/functions/eof.html).

`eof` with empty parentheses refers to the pseudo file accessed via `while (<>)`, which consists of either all the files named in `@ARGV`, or to `STDIN` if there are none.

And in particular:

> Note that this function actually reads a character and then "ungetc"s it, so isn't useful in an interactive context.

But your loop reads from another handle, one called `INPUT_FILE`.

It would make more sense to call `eof(INPUT_FILE)`. But even that probably isn't necessary; your outer loop will terminate when it reaches the end of `INPUT_FILE`.

Some more suggestions, not related to the symptoms you're seeing:

Add

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

near the top of your script, and correct any error messages this produces (`perl -cw script-name` does a compile-only check). You'll need to declare your variables using `my` (`perldoc -f my`). And use consistent indentation; I recommend the same style you'll find in most Perl documentation.